Apache Kafka Mirror Maker 2 - The selected topic is not replicated
Can you help me solve the following problem?
The data is not replicated to the other server.
There are two servers: 192.168.150.151 and 192.168.150.152. Kafka runs in a docker container in both.
The task would be to replicate the data of the OpenWeather_DMZ topic under the Kafka server 192.168.150.151:9092 in the OpenWeather_DMZ topic under the Kafka server 192.168.150.152:9092.
Both servers have this topic. It was created the same way.
The mm2.properties are as follows:
# specify any number of cluster aliases clusters = SourceCluster, TargetCluster 
# connection information for each cluster 
SourceCluster.bootstrap.servers = 192.168.150.151:9092 
TargetCluster.bootstrap.servers = 192.168.150.152:9092 
# enable and configure individual replication flows 
SourceCluster->TargetCluster.enabled = true 
SourceCluster->TargetCluster.topics = OpenWeather_DMZ 
replication.factor=1 
tasks.max = 1 
## Internal Topic Settings ## 
checkpoints.topic.replication.factor=1 
heartbeats.topic.replication.factor=1 
offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor=1 
offset.storage.replication.factor=1 
status.storage.replication.factor=1 
config.storage.replication.factor=1 
# Kafka Settings # Optional: Customize Kafka properties for SourceCluster and TargetCluster as needed

A topic named SourceCluster.OpenWeather_DMZ was created under the server 192.168.150.151, and it contains the desired data, but on the server 192.168.150.152, apart from the creation of these topics, nothing else happens.
mm2-configs.SourceCluster.internal 
mm2-offsets.SourceCluster.internal 
mm2-status.SourceCluster.internal

There is no ERROR, only INFO. Also, on the server ending in 151, the heatbeats topic "proliferates" constantly:
SourceCluster.SourceCluster.SourceCluster.SourceCluster.SourceCluster.heartbeats SourceCluster.SourceCluster.SourceCluster.SourceCluster.heartbeats SourceCluster.SourceCluster.SourceCluster.heartbeats 


:(
After running the command connect-mirror-maker.sh mm2.properties the source cluster looks fine, but the data is not transferred to the target cluster. Port 9092 of server 152 can be seen via telnet from server 151.
